Requesting Help on PCB Design (Power Circuitry for 4AA Batteries)
I’ve been working on a PCB design for my project, and I would appreciate any feedback or recommendations you can offer. It's a very basic schematic, I'm just doing the prototype for the power circuitry for 4AA battery pack now and fixing the overall PCB layout by making the circuit more efficient.
I have gathered all the necessary components and created a basic outline in Altium, I’m very new to PCB design and I'm finding some aspects challenging. I've gained foundational knowledge through an Altium learning course and have some very basic experience in KiCad, but I would appreciate any specific guidance or resources that could help me advance with this schematic.

What I want it to do:
I looked online and found this example circuit flow for a PCB with 4 AA batteries. Please let me know what you think.
Example circuit flow:

4 AA batteries in series (6 V)
Reverse polarity protection
Voltage regulator (linear or buck converter)
Decoupling capacitors
Power switch
PCB power input.
Here are the descriptions of each step and its purpose.

Voltage regulation:
If your PCB operates at a specific voltage (e.g., 3.3 V, 5 V), you will likely need a voltage regulator to step down the voltage from the battery pack. The regulator stabilizes the voltage despite the battery discharge curve, which ensures consistent power delivery to the circuit.
Reverse polarity protection:
To prevent damage in case the batteries are inserted incorrectly, a Schottky diode or a P-channel MOSFET can be placed in the circuit to block current if the polarity is reversed.
Decoupling capacitors:
A capacitor (typically a combination of a larger capacitor like 100 µF and a smaller one like 0.1 µF) is used at the input and output of the voltage regulator to smooth voltage fluctuations and filter noise. These capacitors also help stabilize the output of the regulator.
Power switch:
A power switch can be placed between the battery pack and the regulator to allow manual control over when the PCB is powered on or off.
So I looked for these materials and came up with an example:
4 AA battery holder.
Schottky diode (1N5819 for reverse polarity protection).
Buck converter (LM2576 for 5V output).
Capacitors (100 µF and 0.1 µF ceramic)
Power switch (SPST switch).
(I'm very new to PCB design and would appreciate detailed, step-by-step instructions on how to start. Could you please guide me through the specific steps, as I'm still learning the basics?)
Looking forward to your insights!
Thanks in advance for your help.

HOLD IT... Your voltage regulator U1 cannot support a 6V supply. Before you consider making schematics, please consider going over your design requirements and choosing your parts carefully.

What, exactly, are you powering here?

4AA batteries. This is the battery pack mount I want to connect for the power supply. https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mpd-memory-protection-devices/BC4AAW/66733

Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on Electrical Engineering SE, you’ve granted Stack Exchange the rights to the content you post under the CC BY-SA 4.0 licence, regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your posts can result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your post being locked and your account being temporarily suspended.

( This question has now been locked to prevent further vandalism. )

While the question is quite broad this answer only focuses on one part of the schematic, which is hopefully some helpful feedback. As already mentioned in a comment by Colin there is a problem with the choice of the voltage regulator U1.
The TI TPS61021A datasheet for the 3-A Boost Converter with 0.5-V Ultra Low Input Voltage contains the following in the features:

Input Voltage Range: 0.5 V to 4.4 V
0.9 V Minimum Input Voltage for Startup
Output Voltage Setting Range: 1.8 V to 4.0 V

The absolute maximum rating for the VIN pin is:

4.6 V at DC
4.8 V at 10% duty cycle

I.e. the TPS61021A input voltage range doesn't support a 6V input from a 4 cell AA battery pack, nor a 5 V USB VBus supply (as suggested by one label on the schematic).
The datasheet description contains:

The TPS61021A is capable of outputting 3.3-V voltage and 1.5-A current from a battery discharged to as low as 1.8 V. Capable of operating with 0.5-V input voltage enables the TPS61021A to extend the battery run time.

To be able to continue using a TPS61021A one possible option is to change from using four AA cells at a nominal 6 V battery supply to two C cells to give a nominal 3 V battery supply.
Where the change from AA to C cells is to keep the overall battery run time at least the same. According to List of battery sizes C cells have a capacity ~3 times that of a AA cell.

An answer is that this solution does not match your requirements.
VIN = 4 AA batteries = 3.6V to 6.0V - over battery life.
VOUT = 3.3V, a suggested 5.0V alternate Vout?   For Vout=3.3, VIN is always higher than VIN.  A boost converter such as the TI part you reference will not work for this application. Correct me if I misunderstood your requirements?
